# How to access columns of mysqli_result in PHP

Tags: php, android, sql

I have a query that is retrieving information from a MySQL db that should populate a bio page for a user of an app.

```
$result = mysqli_query($link ,"SELECT `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Description`, `ProfileImage` FROM `Doctors` WHERE `DoctorID` = '$doctor_id'" );
```

My question is, how do I access the columns of the mysqli_result object 'result'? My query should return a single row w/ 4 columns, and I need some way to return these column values back to my Java code.

I have seen examples using fetch_field, but it seems like this function gives you characteristics of the result rather than the actual value of it. I want to return the actual 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'Description', and 'ProfileImage' (stored as a url). What is a way I can do this?

Thank you.

Comment: You're quoting instead of backticking column names - that will not work. If you want the actual column names you need to perform a `DESCRIBE` query.

Comment: did you consider reading the doc? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php